Want to solve issue in making iOS build
when I hit pod install
I get this error
[!] Unable to find a specification for RCT-Folly (= 2024.01.01.00) depended upon by RNScreens
You have either:

out-of-date source repos which you can update with pod repo update or with pod install --repo-update.
mistyped the name or version.
not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Here is my PodFile
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
pod 'RNSVG', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-svg', :version => '12.1.0'



platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'PremPackaging' do
  # Automatically detect and include native modules
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Enables Flipper.
  # Ensure to specify the correct version of Flipper (latest recommended version: 0.125.0)


  # Post-installation hooks to handle Flipper and other native module setup
  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    flipper_post_install(installer)  # Flipper post-install configuration
  end
end

target 'PremPackagingTests' do
  inherit! :complete
  # Additional configurations for test target (if needed)
end

please anyone help me......
I want to run my react native app on iPhone.
Please help me with that

Have you tried pod repo update or  pod install --repo-update

[!] Invalid Podfile file: uninitialized constant Pod::Podfile::FlipperConfiguration.
from /Users/sudhanshusrivastava/Desktop/prem_packaging_ecom_app/ios/Podfile:20
-------------------------------------------
# ```

flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

when I hit pod install... I get this error
Please help me

I have attached my PodFile Above
